# perl Join with array reference

Tags: perl, join, arrayref

I am new to perl.

I am trying to use join with a array reference, but it is not working.

Here is my code.

```
my $arr = {
     'items' => ('home', 'chair', 'table')
};

my $output = join(',', $arr->{'items'});

print $output;
```

It is printing

```
table
```

instead of

```
home,chair,table
```

Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Perl, parens do not create arrays. They only ever sort out precedence. The hashref

```
{ 'items' => ('home', 'chair', 'table') }
```

is the same as

```
{ 'items' => 'home', 'chair' => 'table' }
```

If you want to put an array into a hash, you need to use an arrayref, which you can create with `[ ... ]`:

```
my $hash = { 'items' => ['home', 'chair', 'table'] }
```

Now if you run your code, you'll get something like

```
ARRAY(0x1234567)
```

as output. This is the way *references* are printed out. We need to dereference it in order to join the elements. We can do so with the `@{ ... }` array dereference operator. Then:

```
print join(',', @{ $hash->{items} }), "\n";
```

To learn more about references and complex data structures in Perl, read

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and then
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Awesome answer with all the details I needed. Thanks amon. :)